# Stopping and restarting an animation on hover in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, loops, hover, restart

I'm trying to create an animated button using jQuery that should stop on hover and then restart when it's not hovered.

For the animation I'm using a loop that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function test() {
        $('#box').animate({opacity:0.5}, {duration:750})
        .animate({opacity:1}, {duration:1500})
        .animate({opacity:0.5}, {duration:750, complete: test})
        ;
    });
```

And I tried adding a hover with a .stop() but, then I don't know how to restart the animation. Do you have any suggestions?

Also, I have a little example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/fTpZZ/

Answer (score 2):

the hover() event handler can handle a handlerIn and handlerOut method as the first and second arguments, respectively.

hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )

Create 2 separate functions--one for the "on" state, and one for the "off"

[.hover() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 1):

Working solution: (http://jsfiddle.net/fTpZZ/50/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#box').hover(function() {                   
            $('#box').stop();
            $('#box').animate({opacity:0},1);
        });

        function foo()
        {
            $('#box').animate({opacity:0.5}, 750, function(){
                $('#box').animate({opacity:1}, 1500, function(){
                    $('#box').animate({opacity:0.5}, 750, foo());    
                });
            });             
        }

        foo();          
    });
```

Comment: Are you able to get the animation to restart? It stops (after I enter and leave a few times), but doesn't start again.  FF 3.6.x and FF 4.xb

Comment: I tested in latest Chrome, Firefox 3.6 and Opera 11 and the animation didn't restart when I left the area. Other than that it works great, thanks!